# Disabling right click option in html viewer in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to disable the right click option on the html viewer in silverlight.It is accepted you can avoid the right click on the silverlight page,but when I right click on the html viewer I am getting right click option.I dont want the right click option in the html viewer.Can anyone help me out regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

look at this code -

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
<!-- http://www.spacegun.co.uk -->
    var message = "function disabled"; 
    function rtclickcheck(keyp){ if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" && keyp.which == 3){   alert(message); return false; } 
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) {  alert(message);     return false; } } 
    document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;
</SCRIPT>
```

and also this example:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
//Disable right click script 
var message="Sorry, right-click has been disabled"; 
/////////////////////////////////// 
function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}} 
function clickNS(e) {if 
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) { 
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}} 
if (document.layers) 
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;} 
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;} 
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false") 
// --> 
</SCRIPT>
```

taken from posts:

http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/no_right_click.html

http://www.hypergurl.com/norightclick.html